# MySQL stored procedure issue, generate custom ID's

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a stored procedure for making custom ID, but it was for SQL Server and I tried to convert it to MySQL with help of an online tool, and I get errors and I need help from you guys :(

This stored procedure will produce ID codes for my users, like for admin (AD001, AD002,...etc), first, it will look if there is no value it will generate the first value like (AD001) if there is a value it will get the value and increment it by 1.

This is my SQL Server version of the procedure which works:

```
create procedure admin_code
as
begin
    declare @max int, @no varchar(50), @value varchar(50)

    select @max = isnull(max(cast(right(id_user, 3) as int)), 0) + 1 
    from admin_information

    if @max < 100
        select @no = 'AD' + right('00000' + cast(@max as varchar(50)), 3)
    else if @max >= 100
        select @no = 'AD' + right('0' + cast(@max as varchar(50)),  4)

    if @max >= 1000
        select @no = 'AD' + right('0' + cast(@max as varchar(50)), 5)

    print @no
    select @no

    return 0
end
```

And this is for MySQL

```
create procedure admin_code()
sp_lbl:

begin
declare v_max int;  
declare no varchar(50);  
declare value varchar(50);

select v_max=ISNULL( max(cast(RIGHT(id_user,3)as int)),0)+1 into v_max from admin_information;
if v_max <100 then
set v_no=CONCAT('AD',RIGHT('00000'+CAST(v_max as varchar(50)),3));

elseif
 v_max>=100 then
-- SQLINES LICENSE FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY
set v_no=CONCAT('AD',RIGHT('0'+CAST(v_max as varchar(50)),4));
end if;
if v_max>=1000 then
-- SQLINES LICENSE FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY
set v_no=CONCAT('AD',RIGHT('0'+CAST(v_max as varchar(50)),5))

print;
end if; v_no
-- SQLINES LICENSE FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY
select v_no;
LEAVE sp_lbl 0;
end;
```

This is the online tool I used:

http://www.sqlines.com/online

Error:

[image]

Comment: Post the errors too

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did, is it better ?

Comment: @mr.loop I add the error with some more explanation hope you understand